# split method to output values under each other when reading from a file

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, line

My code works fine however it prints the values side by side instead of under each other line by line. Like this:

```
iatadult,DDD,

iatfirst,AAA,BBB,CCC
```

I have done a diligent search on stackoverflow and none of my solution's seem to work. I know that I have to make the change while the looping is going on. However none of the examples I have seen have worked. Any further understanding or techniques to achieve my goal would be helpful. Whatever I am missing is probably very small. Please help.

```
String folderPath1 = "C:\\PayrollSync\\client\\client_orginal.txt";
File file = new File (folderPath1);
ArrayList<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<>(); // holds all matching client names in array

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));// reads entire file
    String line;

    while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
        if(line.contains("fooa")||line.contains("foob")){
            fileContents.add(line);
        }
        //---------------------------------------
    }
    reader.close();// close reader
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

System.out.println(fileContents);
```

Comment: Java 8: `fileContents.forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Line Feed before you add to `fileContents`.

`fileContents.add(line+"\n");`

Comment: That works however i am getting this output under each other but there is a comma(,) on the second line.

Comment: Can you post that part of the input file?

Answer (score 2):

By printing the list directly as you are doing you are invoking the method `toString()` overridden for the list which prints the contents like this:

```
obj1.toString(),obj2.toString() .. , objN.toString()
```

in your case the `obj*` are of type `String` and the `toString()` override for it returns the string itself. That's why you are seeing all the strings separated by comma.

To do something different, i.e: printing each object in a separate line you should implement it yourself, and you can simply append the new line character(`'\n'`) after each string.

Possible solution in java 8:

```
String result = fileContents.stream().collect(Collectors.joining('\n'));
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Was there some additional code here for looping through the fileContents. it flashed away.

Comment: Other answers explained the same in code. I also added explanation of why are you seeing what are you seeing.

Comment: I added java 8 sample.

Comment: I like this alot better thanks. Its good to see various ways of doing things.

Comment: Question I would like to store the strings i want the while loop to compare against  in an array of strings. I  tried to use a string array with the while loop but it does not work. I would like to do this so I don't have to keep writing .contains("string") for each string. Is there way to do this?

Comment: Yes. `List <String> allStrings = new ArrayList <String>();` and in the loop just add the `currentString` with `allStrings.add(currentString);`.

Comment: So i would change ArrayList<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<>(); to List <String> allStrings = new ArrayList <String>(); ?

Comment: I am thinking something like this to compare against List<String> names = Arrays.asList("lawiat","mc7csrate","iatrapala"); to compare agianst line

Comment: is it possible to show me an example of what your saying i have been trying to implement your solution and i cant figure out out this fits together.

Comment: I think i might now what your saying let me try something

Comment: I actually found the solution on my own regarding the question i asked above thanks for all your help.

Comment: is there a way i can post the solution to my own answer with out changing my main post?

Comment: Yes, just answer your question. You can do it.

Answer (score 1):

A platform-independent way to add a new line:

`fileContents.add(line + System.lineSeparator);`

Answer (score 1):

Below is my full answer. Thanks for your help stackoverflow. It took me all day but I have a full solution.

```
        File file = new File (folderPath1);
        ArrayList<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<>(); // holds all matching client names in array 

         try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));// reads entire file
                String line;

                while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                     String [] names ={"iatdaily","iatrapala","iatfirst","wpolkrate","iatjohnson","iatvaleant"};
                           if (Stream.of(names).anyMatch(line.trim()::contains)) {
                               System.out.println(line);
                               fileContents.add(line + "\n");
                           }
                }
                 System.out.println("---------------");
                reader.close();// close reader
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
```